# vb6 and vb .net interop on vista 64 versus windows 7

Tags: .net, deployment, vb6, uac, dll

I have written a .net dll that I can successfully call from vb6.  Deployment to xp, vista 32, and vista 64 boxes have been working.  It is not working on windows 7 64 bit.  I cannot run `regasm.exe /codebase name.dll` on the end users machine because they are not admins.

Currently my app is deployed in the "c:\Program Files (x86)\application name" directory.

Comment: How are you installing it without admin privileges?

Comment: The initial install has admin privs.  I need to be able to update it without admin privs.

Comment: What are you trying to update? You will not be able to update the DLL in Program Files without admin privileges.  (Unless you modify the ACLs)

Comment: I have the folder permissions set so that a user can update the dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using registration free COM to access the .NET interop assemblies.

Basicly first you have to create assembly manifest with `mt.exe` and optionally re-sign strong names with `sn.exe` like this

```
mt.exe -managedassemblyname:{Your_DLL} -nodependency -out:{Your_DLL}.manifest
mt.exe -manifest {Your_DLL}.manifest -outputresource:%{Your_DLL};1
sn -Ra {Your_DLL} {Your_PFX}
```

Then reference this assembly manifest in your application manifest like this

```
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="{Your_DLL}" version="1.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="hash_here" processorArchitecture="x86" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

where `assemblyIdentity` matches `assemblyIdentity` in assembly manifest of {Your_DLL}.

On client machines both the VB6 executable and .NET dll must be in the same folder. No regasm and no GAC registration needed.

I'm using [UMMM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ummm/) tool to automate the manifest creation process but you can do it manually if it's a one time setup.

Comment: I agree that Reg free comm is the best way to handle this.  We have been having a few issues.  It is still my long term goal.  I will try out the UMMM tool.

Comment: I was able to use the mt and sn commands listed above to get reg free comm to work.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

[I solved this by running `regasm` with the `/regfile` option, and replacing HKLM with HKCU in the resulting `.reg`  file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354581/com-interop-without-regasm/1613018#1613018)

If you need more precise instructions, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is it working on Windows 7 64 bit?  I replaced HKLM with HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node.  This works on vista 64 but not windows 7 ....  I suspect Wow6432Node issues.

Comment: Thanks for the help SLaks.  I read that Wow6432Node was necessary to run since the vb6 app is 32 bit.  I will remove it and give it a try.

Comment: I took an axe to Wow6432Node and it started working on win7 64 bit.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested I have built a small powershell script that is run automatically in the build.

VMIS is the name of the program.
VMISLIB.dll is the name of the .net dll.

Comment: #this will only work on a 64 bit box because of the x86 file path
#run regasm and create initial file

cd "\Program Files (x86)\VMIS"
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\VMIS\RegAsm' /regfile /codebase VMISLIB.dll

#create file for 32 bit machines
$file1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMIS\VMISLIB.reg"
$file2 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMIS\VMISLIBdeploy.reg"
$match = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"
$replacement = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes"
$content = Get-Content $file1
$content = $content -creplace $match,$replacement
$content | Set-Content $file2

Comment: #take out the x86 stuff for a 32 bit box
$match = " \\(x86\\)"
$replacement = ""
$content = Get-Content $file2
$content = $content -creplace $match,$replacement
$content | Set-Content $file2

Answer (score 0):

Deployment requires admin rights.  It's *supposed* to fail in this case.

Comment: It is working on Vista and XP without admin rights.  I want to update an existing dll ...