# Using RegServer or something similar without admin rights

Tags: .net, com, managed-c++, out-of-process

I have a a program which includes a managed c++ out of process com server. Right now during the install it's registered with the /RegServer flag. This all works fine in its current implementation.

What I would like to do is register this server in the user space and avoid the need for admin rights.

I have tried to search stackoverflow and google but I have only found one article on codeproject that created a third party utility to do this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3505/RegSvrEx-An-Enchanced-COM-Server-Registration-Util

As best I can tell there isn't a way to register a com server in the user space instead of root space normally. Is this possible and can anyone point me in the general direction?

Comment: Possible with `RegOverridePredefKey` API: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23073183/1768303

Comment: Awesome thank you! I'll check it out though it might take me a bit to confirm if this works or not. I searched and I assumed I wasn't the only person to want to try this but I couldn't figure out what to search for.